# Matthew 24:34 Translation

Tags: greek, matthew, olivet-discourse, bible

> ἀμὴν λέγω ὑμῖν ὅτι οὐ μὴ παρέλθῃ ἡ γενεὰ αὕτη ἕως ἂν πάντα ταῦτα γένηται.
>
> Truly I tell you, this generation will certainly not pass away until all these things have happened.

Can "γένηται" be translated as "become" in the sense of beginning "until these things develop/begin" making the sentence more open to events that take time?

(sorry for any spelling mistakes, my first language isn't English)

Comment: Welcome to BHSX.  Thanks for your question.  Please remember to take the tour (link below left) to better understand how this site works.

Comment: "This generation" is the generation of the Jews that will finally repent. In Mt. 21 Jesus cursed the fig tree as a sign of fruitfulness of His generation. The future generation will be the fig tree that is ready to bring fruit.  "For I tell you, you will not see me again until you say, ‘Blessed is he who comes in the name of the Lord.’"

Comment: The word does not mean "begin" but happen: NET uses "take place" in Matt 5:18 and in this verse. The meaning is that everything will take place or happen.

Answer (score 1):

The operative verb in Matt 24L34 is γίνομαι (ginomai).  In this verse the for is γένηται which is aorist subjunctive middle voice.  Thus, it must be literally translated, "shall have happened" or similar.  (English does not have an exact form of this part of the Greek verb.)

The verb γίνομαι (ginomai), meaning "*I come into being, am born, become, come about, happen*." (Strongs) is used in several ways such as (Thayer):

1. to become, ie. to come into existence, begin to exit, receive being
2. to become equivalent to to come to pass, happen, of events
3. to arise, appear in history, come upon the stage: of men appearing in public
4. to be made, done, finished
5. to become, be made, "in passages where it is specified who or what a person or thing is or has been rendered, as respects quality, condition, place, rank, character" (Wahl, Clavis Apocr. V. T., p. 101)

Note that this verb does not ever mean anything like, "begin", "start", "initiate", etc.  Thus, the answer to the OP's question is, "No".  The verb cannot be translated, "to begin".

Answer (score 0):

> Now therefore I have commanded to hinder those men from building the city, **and heed to be taken that there be no more done in it**; and that those wicked workers proceed no further to the annoyance of kings, 1 Es. 2:28-29 KJA

> καὶ προνοηθῆναι ὅπως μηθὲν παρὰ **ταῦτα γένηται** καὶ μὴ προβῇ ἐπὶ πλεῖον τὰ τῆς κακίας εἰς τὸ βασιλεῖς ἐνοχλῆσαι (1 Es. 2:24 LXX)

The phrase **ταῦτα γένηται** translated in the sense of "despite that it is done and does not bother the king with more things"